# Change Image's Position based on scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I have a back to top image that popups when the user scrolls beyond 280.  The issue is when you reach the bottom the image is over links in the footer.  So I want to change the position of the image once the user is about 90px from the very bottom of the page - I want "bottom": '35px' to be 95.  The page height is always changing fyi.  Code I have:

```
function update() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
        $('#btt').animate({
            "bottom": '35px'
            }, 300);
    }

    else {
        $('#btt').animate({
            "bottom": '-80px'
        }, 300);
        }
    }
setInterval(update, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to check for the scroll position only when the page has been scrolled rather than just checking every 1/2 second.

I've put together a working demo of what I think you want here: **http://jsfiddle.net/swpqpv4r/5/**

Basically we need to look at the scroll position of the *bottom* of the window as we scroll instead of the top by using `document.body.scrollTop + $(win).height()`.  Normaly we might want to worry about what could happen if the window were to be resized, but we calculate this each time inside of the scroll event, so it shouldn't be an issue if the window changes sizes.

Next we need to know when the top of the footer has scrolled above the bottom of the window.  We can use `$("#footer").position().top;` to see where it's top position is.

Hopefully the code is commented enough to help explain it.  Let me know if you have any questions.

**HTML**

```
<header>Top</header>
<br><br><br> <!-- Lots of these for testing -->
<footer id="footer">Bottom</footer>
<a id="btt" href="javascript:{};">Back to top</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    //select once and re-use later
    var $win = $(window);
    var $btt = $("#btt");
    var $foot = $("#footer");
    var bttDisplay = 500;
    var footerHeight = $foot.outerHeight();
    var footerTop = $foot.position().top;

    function updateScroll() {
        var scrollBottom = document.body.scrollTop + $win.height();

        if (scrollBottom >= bttDisplay && scrollBottom <= footerTop) {
            //show it by setting the bottom position to 0
            animateBtt(0);
        }else if (scrollBottom >= footerTop) {
            //move it up above the footer's top position
            animateBtt(footerHeight);
        }else {
            //hide it by setting the bottom position to the negative value of it's height
            animateBtt($btt.height() * -1);
        }
    }

    function animateBtt(pos){
        $btt.animate({
            "bottom": pos
        }, 300);
    }

    //run initially
    updateScroll();

    //Create a var to hold the timer
    var scrollTimer = null;
    $win.on("scroll",function(ev){
        //when scrolling, clear the timer
        clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
        //Now set the timer to run a function after a small delay.
        //This prevents the update from happening too many times when you scroll
        scrollTimer = setTimeout(updateScroll, 50);
    });

    //click to scroll back up
    $btt.on("click",function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0},300);
    })

});
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header, footer{
    background: #CCC;
    padding: 10px;
}
#btt{
    position:fixed;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    bottom: -30px;
    right:0;
    background: #F00;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: More like this... solved it, but would like not to do the interval and only updated on scroll change.

`function update() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
   $('#btt').animate({
    "bottom": '120px'
    }, 300);
  }
  else if  ($(window).scrollTop() > 300 && $(window).scrollTop() != $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
   $('#btt').animate({
    "bottom": '60px'
    }, 300);
  }
  else {
   $('#btt').animate({
    "bottom": '-80px'
   }, 300);
   }
  }
 setInterval(update, 500);`

Comment: What do you mean?  The solution above will do this on the scroll event instead of on an interval.